# Cloning an array in java

Tags: java, deep-copy, shallow-copy, arrays

Is this the correct way to clone an array? Id like to create a deep copy of AccountWithInterface which has a clone method defined within it. Ive already read the difference between deep copy vs. shallow copy so please no links on explaining their differences. Its just syntax which im having trouble with at the moment.

```
     // create object
    AccountWithInterface accountTemplate = new AccountWithInterface(name, balance, id, rate);

    // declare object
    AccountWithInterface[] accountArray = new AccountWithInterface[3];


    // create each accountArray object
    for(int i = 0; i < accountArray.length; i++) {
        accountArray[i] = new AccountWithInterface();
        // copy each element (object)
        accountArray[i] = (AccountWithInterface)accountArray[i].clone();
    }

           public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                 AccountWithInterface acctClone = (AccountWithInterface)super.clone();
                 return acctClone;
           }
```

Comment: Rly? downvote for asking a question on syntax and not 100 links to different sites?

Comment: Don't muck around with `clone()` and `Clonable()`; it's horribly broken and rarely does what you need or expect. Your logic is fine, you just need a "copy constructor" for `AccountWithInterface` that takes an existing `AccountWithInterface` instance, and in the process of instantiating the new one performs a deep copy of all the contents of the existing one to the new one.

Comment: no idea what u mean but i will look up how to create the copy constructor now brian

Comment: Define a constructor in `AccountWithInterface` with the signature: `public AccountWithInterface(AccountWithInterface existing)`. Inside that sonstructor you copy the contents of the old one to the new one you're constructing; that's a deep copy. Be aware that you'll need to deep copy any mutable objects that your `AccountWithInterface` contains as well.